# Oozie coordinator-app: execute job every Nth minute divisible by M

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have an Hive script that I am executing using Oozie coordinator every 10 minutes. When I launched my Oozie coordinator-app, suppose I have started at 08:03, the first workflow starts at that time, the next 08:13, and then 08:23, and so on.

What I want is to execute the workflow every clock time hh:mm, where mm is divisible by 10. Assuming the same scenario above, what I want to happen is this: the first workflow will execute at 08:10, and then 08:20, and so on.

How do I do this in Oozie? How about when every 5 minutes (The last m of the minute is either 5 or 0)? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run a coordinator job at a frequency, you can use the following directives

`<coordinator-app name="app" frequency="10" start="2015-07-10T12:00Z" end="2016-01-01T00:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">`

This would run every 10 minutes, starting exactly at 12:00 UTC time today.  The same goes for running every 5 minutes, just replace `frequency="10"` with `frequency="5"`.  To to have it run every Nth minute divisible by M, you will have to ensure that your `start` parameter is set correctly.

Another option if you are using a more recent version of Oozie (4.1.0) would be to use the cron like scheduler.  This would allow you to schedule Oozie coordinators in a cron-like fashion if you're familiar.  See http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-use-cron-like-scheduling-in-apache-oozie/ and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1306